# Flash Player hijacked by Mac .app publish

Tags: flash

I published my Flash AS3 game as a Mac app and now any swf opened runs my game concurrently behind the intended swf!

Any idea what happened, or how to fix?

I have been selling these games, but haven't had any support issues relating to this, so I think it's a local problem...?

Answer (score 0):

Check your mime setting for .SWF files.  Select a .swf file in your finder and press command+i, or go to the file menu and choose "Get info"

Under the part that says "Open With" I think you will find it is using your published game to open the swf.  If this is the case you can change this back to Flash Player and "Change All".

Otherwise, ooooo nice bug ^_^

Comment: I wish that would have worked! It is opening with Flash Player, and still opens with my game playing behind.
I need an exterminator!